# how to add collection inside a specific document?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i want to add collection called "LikedUsers" in my document path
i want to put what on blue inside the red document without creating new documents (check the images for more understanding)

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pvNg.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snlGb.png)

**Upload to firestore Code:**

````dart
Future getPhoto() async{
FirebaseFirestore fearbase = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
 Reference ref=FirebaseStorage.instance
 .ref()
 .child("${widget.user}/ProfileData")
 .child("Url_$postId");

 await ref.putFile(file!);
downloadUrl=await ref.getDownloadURL();

//  upload image to firestore
// String ido=FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("PostData").doc().id;

await fearbase.collection("users").doc(widget.user)
.collection("PostData/")
.add({"PostUrl":downloadUrl,"ownerName":loggedInUser.username,"userId":loggedInUser.uid,"timestemp":postId,})
.then((DocumentReference ido) => ido.update({"PostId":ido.id}))
.whenComplete(() => Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Image Uploaded successfully .i."));

}
```!
i want to put "LikedUsers" collection inside this path

**Liked Users methode:**
```dart
 void addLike(bool liked){ 

    CollectionReference collectReef=FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users")
    .doc(user!.uid).collection("PostData").doc().collection("LikedUsers");
    liked =!liked;
    if(liked){
      DocumentReference reef=collectReef
            .doc(widget.user);
            reef.set({
              'nameAR':loggedInUser.username,
              'CreationTime':DateTime.now(),
            });
```!

i tried to use DocumentRefernce but no use
````

Answer (score 0):

You should use set and merge:true so you don't overwrite your other data. Your if statements can be amended but in essence what you want.  I didn't go into deep detail on your logic but instead just wrote this so you can use it.  You will need to install the promise package for dart

As a simple example:

```
   const frs = firebase.default.firestore();

   const colRef = "collection1";
   const colRef2 = "collection2";
   const docId = "yourdocid";
   const docId2 = "yourdocid2";
   const item1 = frs.collection(colRef as string).doc(docId as string);
   const item1Data = (await item1.get()).data;
   Promise.resolve(item1Data).then(()=>{
       if(liked===true){
            const item2 = frs.collection(colRef1 as string).doc(docId).collection(colRef2).doc(docId2).set(item1Data,{merge:true})
           return item2
       }
   })
```

if this is a new document being added then you would do this

```
       const frs = firebase.default.firestore();
    
       const colRef = "collection1";
       const colRef2 = "collection2";
       const docId = "yourdocid";
       const item1 = frs.collection(colRef as string).doc(docId as string);
       const item1Data = (await item1.get()).data;
        Promise.resolve(item1Data).then(()=>{
           if(liked===true){
              const item2 = frs.collection(colRef1 as string).doc(docId).collection(colRef2).add(item1Data)
              return item2
            }
        })
```

Comment: yeah your solution it seems working but i need to put "LikedUsers" collection inside the document that i create using getPhoto() methode

Comment: so in that case, the users collection is just a json object, so you can simply set the data on the root collection, make sure you use merge:true

so get the collection items, resolve it then use that response as the data to write to the collection.